# No email notifications with Android app

Tags: support, android-app, email

I installed the Stack Exchange app on my Android-based smartphone. Now I get announcements about new answer/comment only to my smartphone but not to "ordinary" mail. Basically it is difficult to edit/answer using such a small unit; it's more comfortable to use an ordinary PC. Is there any way to have announcements both to smartphone and to ordinary mail (Gmail)?